# How to use Family Sharing on iPhone 4 and other devices?

Tags: iphone, apple-id, ios, family-sharing

I have multiple devices on 1 apple ID (an iPhone 6, iPhone 5s, iPod Touch 5, iPhone 4) and would like the devices to have separate apple IDs. The iPhone 6 and iPhone 5s have separate apple IDs and the iPhone 4 and iPod touch 5 will have the same apple ID. How can I setup the iPhone 4 to use family sharing even though it does not have iOS 8? Is this even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I turned on Family Sharing for my kids on my iPhone 5 that has iOS 8. After entering their emails, I entered their passwords. On their iOS 8 iPads, purchases from all the family members show up, but not on the iPod 4 or iPhone 4.

However, my kids on those devices still have "Ask to buy" show up. If you want them to have access to all of your apps, you could jailbreak (redsn0w for iPod 4 on iOS 6 and evasi0n for iPhone 4 on iOS 7) and install Account Changer. If it weren't for the "Ask to buy," we would have stayed with Account Changer only.

Answer (score 1):

As detailed in [Apple's Family Sharing page](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201060), at the end, it states

> iOS 8 and OS X Yosemite or later are required to set up or join a Family Sharing group and are recommended for full functionality.

As Trig mentioned, some features may still be available on devices that are not running iOS 8 or OS X Yosemite, such as Ask to Buy and Family Photo Sharing.

Answer (score -2):

Check if these two links can help you or not.
https://support.apple.com/en-nz/HT201088
https://support.apple.com/en-nz/HT201085